# How to get all columns after groupby on Dataset<Row> in spark sql 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

First, I am very new to SPARK

I have millions of records in my Dataset and i wanted to groupby with name column and finding names which having maximum age. I am getting correct results but I need all columns in my resultset.

```
Dataset<Row> resultset = studentDataSet.select("*").groupBy("name").max("age");
resultset.show(1000,false);
```

I am getting only name and max(age) in my resultset dataset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your solution you have to try different approach. You was almost there for solution but let me help you understand.

```
Dataset<Row> resultset = studentDataSet.groupBy("name").max("age");
```

now what you can do is you can join the `resultset` with `studentDataSet`

```
Dataset<Row> joinedDS = studentDataset.join(resultset, "name");
```

The problem with `groupBy` this that after applying groupBy you get `RelationalGroupedDataset` so it depends on what next operation you perform like `sum, min, mean, max` etc then the result of these operation joined with `groupBy`

As in you case `name` column is joined with the `max` of `age` so it will return only two columns but if use apply `groupBy` on `age` and then apply `max` on 'age' column you will get two column one is `age` and second is `max(age)`.

**Note** :- code is not tested please make changes if needed
Hope this clears you query

Comment: Hey Thank you !  studentDataset.join(resultset, expression) solved my problem.

Comment: I know it is 1 year old post but still 
Hey Anup ! good to know that you got the solution, Can you help us also by posting your code ?

Comment: Hey Akash and Anup This does not work for me. Even after the join, I am getting only two columns and not the other ones. Does it has something to do with spark version as well. I am using spark 2.1

Comment: I also think the join can produce a second round of shuffling, so I added another solution that does not join at the end AND maintains use of strict Dataset usage (no Dataframes).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer isn't ideal because it requires a join.  Joining big DataFrames can cause a big shuffle that'll execute slowly.

Let's create a sample data set and test the code:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("bob", 20, "blah"),
  ("bob", 40, "blah"),
  ("karen", 21, "hi"),
  ("monica", 43, "candy"),
  ("monica", 99, "water")
).toDF("name", "age", "another_column")
```

This code should run faster with large DataFrames.

```
df
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg(
    max("name").as("name1_dup"), 
    max("another_column").as("another_column"),  
    max("age").as("age")
  ).drop(
    "name1_dup"
  ).show()

+------+--------------+---+
|  name|another_column|age|
+------+--------------+---+
|monica|         water| 99|
| karen|            hi| 21|
|   bob|          blah| 40|
+------+--------------+---+
```

Comment: .agg(
    max("name").as("name1_dup"), 
    max("another_column").as("another_column"),  
    max("age").as("age")
  )  gives compile time exception

Comment: If you change the row `("monica", 43, "candy")` to `("monica", 43, "zebra")`, this example does _not_ work. @AnujMehra - The code interprets for me in the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

What your trying to achieve is

1. group rows by age
2. reduce each group to 1 row with maximum age

This alternative achieves this output without use of aggregate

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object TestJob5 {

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName(this.getClass.getName.replace("$", ""))
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

    val rawDf = Seq(
      ("Moe",  "Slap",  7.9, 118),
      ("Larry",  "Spank",  8.0, 115),
      ("Curly",  "Twist", 6.0, 113),
      ("Laurel", "Whimper", 7.53, 119),
      ("Hardy", "Laugh", 6.0, 118),
      ("Charley",  "Ignore",   9.7, 115),
      ("Moe",  "Spank",  6.8, 118),
      ("Larry",  "Twist", 6.0, 115),
      ("Charley",  "fall", 9.0, 115)
    ).toDF("name", "requisite", "funniness_of_requisite", "age")

    rawDf.show(false)
    rawDf.printSchema

    val nameWindow = Window
      .partitionBy("name")

    val aggDf = rawDf
      .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
      .withColumn("maxFun", max("funniness_of_requisite").over(nameWindow))
      .withColumn("count", count("name").over(nameWindow))
      .withColumn("minId", min("id").over(nameWindow))
      .where(col("maxFun") === col("funniness_of_requisite") && col("minId") === col("id") )
      .drop("maxFun")
      .drop("minId")
      .drop("id")

    aggDf.printSchema

    aggDf.show(false)
  }

}
```

bear in mind that a group could potentially have more than 1 row with max age so you need to pick one by some logic. In the example I assume it doesn't matter so I just assign a unique number to choose

Answer (score 1):

Noting that a subsequent join is extra shuffling and some of the other solutions seem inaccurate in the returns or even turn the Dataset into Dataframes, I sought a better solution. Here is mine:

```
case class People(name: String, age: Int, other: String)   
val df = Seq(
  People("Rob", 20, "cherry"),
  People("Rob", 55, "banana"),
  People("Rob", 40, "apple"),
  People("Ariel", 55, "fox"),
  People("Vera", 43, "zebra"),
  People("Vera", 99, "horse")
).toDS

val oldestResults = df
 .groupByKey(_.name)
 .mapGroups{ 
    case (nameKey, peopleIter) => {
        var oldestPerson = peopleIter.next  
        while(peopleIter.hasNext) {
            val nextPerson = peopleIter.next
            if(nextPerson.age > oldestPerson.age) oldestPerson = nextPerson 
        }
        oldestPerson
    }
  }    
  oldestResults.show
```

The following produces:

```
+-----+---+------+
| name|age| other|
+-----+---+------+
|Ariel| 55|   fox|
|  Rob| 55|banana|
| Vera| 99| horse|
+-----+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that aggregate functions reduce the rows and therefore you need to specify which of the rows age you want with a reducing function. If you want to retain all rows of a group (warning! this can cause explosions or skewed partitions) you can collect them as a list. You can then use a UDF (user defined function) to reduce them by your criteria, in this example funniness_of_requisite. And then expand columns belonging to the reduced row from the single reduced row with another UDF .
For the purpose of this answer I assume you wish to retain the age of the person who has the max funniness_of_requisite.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType}

import scala.collection.mutable


object TestJob4 {

def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(this.getClass.getName.replace("$", ""))
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val rawDf = Seq(
  (1, "Moe",  "Slap",  7.9, 118),
  (2, "Larry",  "Spank",  8.0, 115),
  (3, "Curly",  "Twist", 6.0, 113),
  (4, "Laurel", "Whimper", 7.53, 119),
  (5, "Hardy", "Laugh", 6.0, 18),
  (6, "Charley",  "Ignore",   9.7, 115),
  (2, "Moe",  "Spank",  6.8, 118),
  (3, "Larry",  "Twist", 6.0, 115),
  (3, "Charley",  "fall", 9.0, 115)
).toDF("id", "name", "requisite", "funniness_of_requisite", "age")

rawDf.show(false)
rawDf.printSchema

val rawSchema = rawDf.schema

val fUdf = udf(reduceByFunniness, rawSchema)

val nameUdf = udf(extractAge, IntegerType)

val aggDf = rawDf
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg(
    count(struct("*")).as("count"),
    max(col("funniness_of_requisite")),
    collect_list(struct("*")).as("horizontal")
  )
  .withColumn("short", fUdf($"horizontal"))
  .withColumn("age", nameUdf($"short"))
  .drop("horizontal")

aggDf.printSchema

aggDf.show(false)
}

def reduceByFunniness= (x: Any) => {

val d = x.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]]

val red = d.reduce((r1, r2) => {

  val funniness1 = r1.getAs[Double]("funniness_of_requisite")
  val funniness2 = r2.getAs[Double]("funniness_of_requisite")

  val r3 = funniness1 match {
    case a if a >= funniness2 =>
      r1
    case _ =>
      r2
  }

  r3
})

red
}

def extractAge = (x: Any) => {

val d = x.asInstanceOf[GenericRowWithSchema]

d.getAs[Int]("age")
}
 }

  d.getAs[String]("name")
}
}
```

here is the output

```
+-------+-----+---------------------------+-------------------------------+---+
|name   |count|max(funniness_of_requisite)|short                          
|age|
+-------+-----+---------------------------+-------------------------------+---+
|Hardy  |1    |6.0                        |[5, Hardy, Laugh, 6.0, 18]     
|18 |
|Moe    |2    |7.9                        |[1, Moe, Slap, 7.9, 118]       
|118|
|Curly  |1    |6.0                        |[3, Curly, Twist, 6.0, 113]    
|113|
|Larry  |2    |8.0                        |[2, Larry, Spank, 8.0, 115]    
|115|
|Laurel |1    |7.53                       |[4, Laurel, Whimper, 7.53, 119]|119|
|Charley|2    |9.7                        |[6, Charley, Ignore, 9.7, 115] |115|
+-------+-----+---------------------------+-------------------------------+---+
```