# get columns post group by in pyspark with dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I see couple of posts [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479072/how-to-get-all-columns-after-groupby-on-datasetrow-in-spark-sql-2-1-0) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409875/how-to-get-other-columns-when-using-spark-dataframe-groupby) which are relevant to my question. However while following post1 solution I am running into below error.

```
joinedDF = df.join(df_agg, "company")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1050, in join
    jdf = self._jdf.join(other._jdf, on, how)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Entire code snippet

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/ec2-user/techcrunch/TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv")

df_agg = df.groupby("company").agg(func.sum("raisedAmt").alias("TotalRaised")).orderBy("TotalRaised", ascending = False).show()

joinedDF = df.join(df_agg, "company")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the second line you have .show at the end

```
df_agg = df.groupby("company").agg(func.sum("raisedAmt").alias("TotalRaised")).orderBy("TotalRaised", ascending = False).show()
```

remove it like this:

```
df_agg = df.groupby("company").agg(func.sum("raisedAmt").alias("TotalRaised")).orderBy("TotalRaised", ascending = False)
```

and your code should work.

You used an action on that df and assigned it to df_agg variable, thats why your variable is NoneType(in python) or Unit(in scala)

Comment: Thank you so much - I don't run into any error - however post join I loose the groupby and aggregation which happened in df_agg

Comment: After join you loose the TotalRaised column ?
Please mark the answer

Comment: nope I loose the groupby and orderBy operation performed

Comment: Looking at your code, that behavior is normal. 
You have "df" variable which is raw data, after that you have df_agg which is aggregated.
After that you are joining the first one("df", non aggregated) with df_agg(aggregated), so for each row from your "df" you are bringing the TotalRaised column .

If you want only the aggregated data us df_agg