# how to rename the Columns Produced by count() function in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the below df:

```
+------+-------+--------+
|student|  vars|observed|
+------+-------+--------+
|  1|   ABC   |      19|
|  1|    ABC   |       1|
|  2|    CDB   |       1|
|  1|    ABC   |       8|
|   3|   XYZ   |       3|
|  1|    ABC   |     389|
|   2|   CDB   |     946|
|  1|    ABC   |     342|
|+------+-------+--------+
```

I wanted to add **a new frequency column** groupBy two columns "student", "vars" in SCALA.

```
val frequency = df.groupBy($"student", $"vars").count()
```

This code generates a "count" column with the frequencies **BUT losing observed column from the df**.

I would like to create a new df as follows without losing "observed" column

```
+------+-------+--------+------------+
|student|  vars|observed|total_count |
+------+-------+--------+------------+
|  1|   ABC   |        9|22
|  1|    ABC   |       1|22
|  2|    CDB   |       1|7
|  1|    ABC   |       2|22
|   3|   XYZ   |       3|3
|  1|    ABC   |       8|22
|   2|   CDB   |       6|7
|  1|    ABC   |       2|22
|+------+-------+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: How do you want to do that if you're not grouping by `observed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly but there are couple of ways,

1. You can join original df with count df. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479072/how-to-get-all-columns-after-groupby-on-datasetrow-in-spark-sql-2-1-0/41483738)
2. You collect the `observed` column while doing aggregation and `explode` it again

With `explode`:

```
 val frequency = df.groupBy("student", "vars").agg(collect_list("observed").as("observed_list"),count("*").as("total_count")).select($"student", $"vars",explode($"observed_list").alias("observed"), $"total_count")

scala> frequency.show(false)
+-------+----+--------+-----------+
|student|vars|observed|total_count|
+-------+----+--------+-----------+
|3      |XYZ |3       |1          |
|2      |CDB |1       |2          |
|2      |CDB |946     |2          |
|1      |ABC |389     |5          |
|1      |ABC |342     |5          |
|1      |ABC |19      |5          |
|1      |ABC |1       |5          |
|1      |ABC |8       |5          |
+-------+----+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use Window functions as well

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("student","vars")
val frequency  = df.withColumn("total_count", count(col("student")) over windowSpec)
      .show


+-------+----+--------+-----------+
|student|vars|observed|total_count|
+-------+----+--------+-----------+
|3      |XYZ |3       |1          |
|2      |CDB |1       |2          |
|2      |CDB |946     |2          |
|1      |ABC |389     |5          |
|1      |ABC |342     |5          |
|1      |ABC |19      |5          |
|1      |ABC |1       |5          |
|1      |ABC |8       |5          |
+-------+----+--------+-----------+
```